# Sequelize "is not associated" model problem

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Got a problem with associations using sequelize.

**models/Category.js**

```
import { sequelize } from '@/utils/server/db'
import { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize'

class Category extends Model {}
Category.init(
{
CategoryID: {
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
primaryKey: true,
autoIncrement: true,
},
CategoryName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
Description: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
},
{
sequelize,
modelName: 'Category',
tableName: 'Categories',
timestamps: false,
}
)

export default Category
```

**models/Product.js**

```
import { sequelize } from '@/utils/server/db'
import { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize'

class Product extends Model {}

Product.init(
{
ProductID: {
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
primaryKey: true,
autoIncrement: true,
},
Name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
Description: { type: DataTypes.STRING(500), allowNull: false },
Price: { type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2), allowNull: false },
InStock: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
CreatedAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE, defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW },
UpdatedAt: {
type: DataTypes.DATE,
defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
onUpdate: DataTypes.NOW,
},
},
{
sequelize,
modelName: 'Product',
tableName: 'Products',
timestamps: false,
}
)
```

export default Product

**models/Index.js**

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize'
import { sequelize } from '@/utils/server/db'
import User from '@/models/User'
import ShoppingCart from './ShoppingCart'
import Order from './Order'
import CartItem from './CartItem'
import Product from './Product'
import Category from './Category'

// Many-to-Many: Product \<--\> Category
Product.belongsToMany(Category, {
through: 'Products_has_Categories',
foreignKey: 'Products_ProductID',
otherKey: 'Categories_CategoryID',
})

Category.belongsToMany(Product, {
through: 'Products_has_Categories',
foreignKey: 'Categories_CategoryID',
otherKey: 'Products_ProductID',
})

module.exports = {
sequelize,
Sequelize,
User,
Products_has_Categories,
ShoppingCart,
CartItem,
Product,
Category,
Order,
}
```

My idea was to fetch all data from products while also including its categories, but im getting this error:

*Error fetching products: EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Category is not associated to Product!*

Question is, what am I missing?

I've tried putting associations inside each specific model, but to no avail

edit: To clarify, a product is meant to be able to have many categories such as man, jacket, winter for example

Comment: it is unclear what relations ship type you have but when you have a m:n relationship you should take a look at https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/

Comment: Please show the module where you execute this query (imports and the query itself)